# Assembly-Console Mode One Character

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios

Hello I am beginner here on the forum and I started a short time to program in assembly but I am still beginner and would like to take a few questions .

1-and possible to put background images??
2-Is it possible to customize the pointer of the cursor with a image?
3-MS-DOS. com files,. exe programs run in an assembly-made system?

---

Well my goal is to create a system prompt but I am beginner in assembly and I am learning to do yet and mixed two codes to generate what I need, but do not understand why when I type 1 character only and for I have tried several methods how to use JMP or M Udar the instructions and registers.If anyone knows help me I thank you very much.

My Code:

```
   DATA SEGMENT
MESSAGE DB "PROMPT>","$"
COMMAND DB ?
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT

START:

ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE

;:::::::BACKGROUND (COLOR"S/IMAGES):::::::::
MOV AH,00h      ; Set video mode
MOV AL,000h      ; Mode 3 (Color text)
INT 10H
MOV AX, 0600h        ; AH=06(scroll up window), AL=00(entire window)
MOV BH,10000100b    ; left nibble for background (blue), right nibble for foreground (light gray)
MOV CX, 0000h        ; CH=00(top), CL=00(left)
MOV DH, 50     ; DH=19(bottom), DL=50(right)
MOV DL , 50
INT 10h
;:::::END BACKGROUND:::::::::::::::::::::::




;:::::::POMPT:::::::::::
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA DX,MESSAGE
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV AH,1
INT 21H
MOV COMMAND,AH
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
ENDS
END START
;:::::END PROMPT:::::::
```

Comment: mode 3 is pure text mode, so no ... you cannot do anything with graphics. see http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html for more information about int 10

Answer (score 2):

Let's correct some problems:

> ```
> MOV AH,00h      ; Set video mode
> MOV AL,000h      ; Mode 3 (Color text)
> INT 10H
> ```

The comment says video mode 3 which has 80 columns and 25 rows, but the code asks for video mode 0 which has only 40 columns and 25 rows.

```
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h
```

---

> ```
> MOV AX, 0600h        ; AH=06(scroll up window), AL=00(entire window)
> MOV BH,10000100b    ; left nibble for background (blue), right nibble for foreground (light gray)
> MOV CX, 0000h        ; CH=00(top), CL=00(left)
> MOV DH, 50     ; DH=19(bottom), DL=50(right)
> MOV DL , 50
> INT 10h
> ```

On an 80x25 screen the bottomright is located at (79,24). Therefore you need to set `DL=79` and `DH=24`.
A 'left nibble' that holds 1000b does not represent blue. That bitpattern corresponds to dark gray. If you want a blue background you need to specify 0001b in the **high nibble** of `BH` (bits 4-7).
Also a 'right nibble' that holds 0100b does not represent light gray. That bitpattern corresponds to red. If you want a white character color you need to specify 0111b in the **low nibble** of `BH` (bits 0-3).

```
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh, 00010111b ;White (= light gray) on blue background
xor cx, cx        ;(0,0)
mov dx, 184Fh     ;(79,24)
int 10h
```

---

```
MOV AH,1
INT 21H
MOV COMMAND,AH
```

The DOS RetrieveCharacter function returns the character in `AL`. You've mistakenly copied from `AH`.

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov COMMAND, al
```

---

> 1-and possible to put background images?? 2-Is it possible to customize the pointer of the cursor with a image? 3-MS-DOS. com files,. exe programs run in an assembly-made system?

1. On a text video screen you can put a background image but it won't be photo-realistic because there are just too few pixels.
2. If you would manage your very own 'cursor' and redefine one of the character shapes for that. A lot of work for a beginner...
3. Why not? The programming language you use or that the system's developers used does not matter for running an executable.